# Update Cassandra Via python

Tags: python, python-3.x, cassandra

I'm quite new to python and I am trying to Update cassandra table via python. When i run the code following error appears.

```
type error not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

error was in following line, is there anything wrong with the formatting with following code,

```
session.execute('UPDATE CourseAssignment SET value = \'%s\'  WHERE key = \'SYSTEM\'', (jsonObject))
```

"value" is a json object which is stored in a text column of cassandra.

```
jsonObjectNew = json.dumps(jsonObject, indent=4, sort_keys=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is because your string is malformed. In this case, it would be better to split the command in many lines for readability:

```
command = """
UPDATE "CourseAssignment"
SET "value" = '%s'
WHERE "key" = "SYSTEM"
"""
```

Using the triple quotes, don't need escaping the inner quotes.

Now, to incorporate your JSON object, you can do:

```
import json
jsonObject = {"one": 1, "two": [1, 10], "three": "string", "four": {"other":"etc."}}
jsonObjectNew = json.dumps(jsonObject, indent=4, sort_keys=True)

print(command % jsonObjectNew)

''' prints:
UPDATE "CourseAssignment"
SET "value" = '{
    "four": {
        "other": "etc."
    },
    "one": 1,
    "three": "string",
    "two": [
        1,
        10
    ]
}'
WHERE "key" = "SYSTEM"
'''
```

To use this command in your `session.execute()` command, don't use the `%` as you do with the print command, to prevent SQL injection and to assure proper escaping. Use the syntax recommended by your [cassandra python driver](http://datastax.github.io/python-driver/api/cassandra/cluster.html#cassandra.cluster.Session.execute):

execute(statement[, parameters][, timeout][, trace][, custom_payload])

```
session.execute(command, jsonObjectNew)
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for the feedback. Still getting the same error.

`TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting`

Comment: Found a fix. Thanks.